# Itertools.permutations across lists in strict order python

Tags: python, python-itertools

Say I had three lists as such:

```
list_1 = ['hello1', 'world1', 'foo1']
list_2 = ['hello2', 'world2', 'foo2']
list_3 = ['hello3', 'world3', 'foo3']
```

Is it possible to achieve - through for example itertools.combinations() or itertools.permutations - that only the following combinations are returned:

```
combs = ['hello1', 'world1', 'foo1'], ['hello1', 'world2', foo1'], ...
['hello1', 'world1', foo2'], ... ['hello3', 'world2', foo2'], ...
```

In other words, I want to make sure that the permutation respects the order as it existed in each of the original lists. I'm sure there must be a simple way but I cannot seem to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you're describing looks like the cartesian product of `['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3']` and `['world1', 'world2', 'world3']` and `['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']`, not permutations.  Look at `itertools.product` and reshape your data to put all the "hellos" in one list, all the "worlds" in another, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `itertools.product()`:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> list(it.product(*zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)))
[('hello1', 'world1', 'foo1'),
 ('hello1', 'world1', 'foo2'),
 ('hello1', 'world1', 'foo3'),
 ('hello1', 'world2', 'foo1'),
 ...
 ('hello3', 'world3', 'foo1'),
 ('hello3', 'world3', 'foo2'),
 ('hello3', 'world3', 'foo3')]
```